# ipyleaflet draws?

Tags: python, leaflet-draw, jupyter-notebook

If I draw a circle with map control in a map, how can I store in a variable?

```
from ipyleaflet import Map, basemaps, basemap_to_tiles, DrawControl
watercolor = basemap_to_tiles(basemaps.Stamen.Watercolor)
m = Map(layers=(watercolor, ), center=(50, 354), zoom=5)
draw_control = DrawControl()

draw_control.circle = {
    "shapeOptions": {
        "fillColor": "#efed69",
        "color": "#efed69",
        "fillOpacity": 1.0
    }
}
m.add_control(draw_control)
m
```

I would like to save all circles that I draw in a geopandas dataframe

Answer (score 5):

Going from the [Draw Control example](https://github.com/jupyter-widgets/ipyleaflet/blob/master/examples/DrawControl.ipynb) you can add a callback to the Draw Control that will get passed the GeoJSON from the feature:

```python
from ipyleaflet import Map, basemaps, basemap_to_tiles, DrawControl
watercolor = basemap_to_tiles(basemaps.Stamen.Watercolor)
m = Map(layers=(watercolor, ), center=(50, 354), zoom=5)
draw_control = DrawControl()

draw_control.circle = {
    "shapeOptions": {
        "fillColor": "#efed69",
        "color": "#efed69",
        "fillOpacity": 1.0
    }
}

feature_collection = {
    'type': 'FeatureCollection',
    'features': []
}

def handle_draw(self, action, geo_json):
    """Do something with the GeoJSON when it's drawn on the map"""    
    feature_collection['features'].append(geo_json)

draw_control.on_draw(handle_draw)

m.add_control(draw_control)
m
```

Then as you draw features on the map they'll be added to the GeoJSON feature collection, which you can save to disk, or process into a geodataframe, etc...

One last quick note: when drawing a circle, it gets recorded as a point, with a `'radius'` in the `'style'` property in the geometry, e.g.:

```
{'type': 'Feature',
 'properties': {'style': {'stroke': True,
   'color': '#efed69',
   'weight': 4,
   'opacity': 0.5,
   'fill': True,
   'fillColor': '#efed69',
   'fillOpacity': 1,
   'clickable': True,
   'radius': 112071.0363887026}},
 'geometry': {'type': 'Point', 'coordinates': [359.56631, 48.992714]}}
```